# HTML Organization Microdata Just On About Us Page Or Front Page Also

Tags: html, seo, microdata

This is more of a personal preference question than a right/wrong question...

I have an "about us" page that is filled with schema.org microdata.  We have name/address/phone/etc... on our front page, as well.

Is there any point including that microdata on the front page?  It seems like it would be better for search engines to only have 1 page to point to.  At the same time, though, it seems like 1 page should be the front page.

Comment: Pretty much the same question: [1](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20208881/1591669), [2](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/54344/17633), [3](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/58431/17633), [4](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/35121/17633).

Answer (score 0):

I'd put it on both. Let Google figure out the ranking. In the “worst” case, someone searching for your organization will see two Google results with rich snippets.