# How to use Microdata throughout a LocalBusiness website

Tags: html, schema.org, microdata

I am getting involved into Microdata and rich snippets for leading better search results. I am kind of confused about where to set the `itemscope` for a `LocalBusiness` and if it is good or bad to have it repeated through out the whole website over and over.

For example on the header that repeats all over the site, page after page, I have the business name, telephone, address, logo, description, etc. Is it good to repeat the same `itemscope` over and over on each page, or it should be only added to one page, for instance only on the index or only on the contact page?

Simplified version (no address, etc.):

```
<section itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/LocalBusiness">
     <div id="logo">
       <div class="wrapper">
        <img itemprop="logo" src="images/logo.png" alt="My Company Logo" title="My Company" />
        <h1 itemprop="name">My Cmpany</h1>
       </div>
    </div>
    <div id="tel1"> 
        <a href="tel:+5160000001" itemprop="telephone">5160000001</a>
    </div>
     <div id="tel2">
        <a itemprop="telephone" href="tel:+5160000000">5160000000</a>
    </div>
</section>
```

Another question is, if I have a page with a list of partners and their contact information, is it ok to repeat several `itemscope` attributes and `itemtype="LocalBusiness"` for each business or this might mislead Google about the original `LocalBusiness` of the site?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add the Microdata on every page [… because of reasons](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/54703/17633).

If you have a page where your business data is duplicated (e.g., a contact page where the business contact information is in the site header and in the page body), you should only markup *one* of these instances. Otherwise you’d create *two* `LocalBusiness` entities for the same entity.

If you have a page where your *and* partner business data is contained, you should mark up each business separately. So each business entity is represented by an own `LocalBusiness` entity.

Comment: Thanks unor! it makes sense, just to be 100% sure do you know of any reference that explains the entity structure?

Comment: @EddyXP: I used the term "entity" here for a lack of a better one; I guess neither schema.org nor Microdata/RDFa use it that way. -- Sorry, I don’t have a specific reference, only what I know about [Microdata/RDFa](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/53140/17633), as schema.org is a vocabulary that can be used with both syntaxes. Feel free to wait to see if someone comes up with one :)

Comment: Great unor, thanks a lot, to be honest I am also creating a document explaining how to use Microdata and I will like to use reference to all documentation available. BTW I know exactly what you meant by "entity" I didn't mean to be so specific on the term but trying to speak the same language. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Since RDFa is a serialization of RDF (Resource Description Framework), the native term would have been "resource". You might use this for testing: http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution is to use `json-ld`.
So with that you don't have to mix html and the Microdata and I would say a little bit easier to use.

This is the post in which they talked about that.
http://blog.schema.org/2013/06/schemaorg-and-json-ld.html

Possible Eg for LocalBusiness:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
    "@context": "http://schema.org",
    "@type": "LocalBusiness",
    "url": "http://www.your-site.com",
    "logo": "http://www.your-site.com/img/logo.png",
    "name": "Bussiness name",
    "description": "Lorem ipsum..",
    "telephone": "+61 ... ...",
    "address":
    {
      "@type": "PostalAddress",
      "streetAddress": "Your street 20",
      "addressLocality": "Melbourne",
      "addressRegion": "Victoria",
      "addressCountry": "Australia"
    }
}
</script>
```

You can check this sintax using [this](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/).